# Service in My website to post Photos on Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I've searched a lot and I see that offline_access on fb is deprecated. So, I have a website hat needs to Post a photo at the Client's wall (Post at site and Facebook too), but I want to store the login data (via token or something like that), I read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal/) that I can't store it.

There is another way to post on wall or my client will need to Post manually on his fb?

**Edit:** My website is in one server, the admin is in another server, I'll make a call from admin server to site in a page that stores login information (*if it's possible*) and post on his wall a photo.

Thanks

Note: I've searched a lot since yesterday I didn't found anything like that, if you have a similar post with the answer please let me know.

Comment: You want to use the Facebook PHP SDK to request an access token from the user. You can then use that to issue calls to the Graph API for actions such as posting to the user’s feed.

Comment: I'm using that in a "Vote in photo app", but in this app I need to store some token to login without him login and do this proccess because the admin is at one server and the site is in another...

Comment: If you have an access token for a user, then you can use that to perform actions as the user, whether they’re logged in or not.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't using Graph API, just a simples login... now I realize what you was talking about. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the **user's access token** you can use that token to perform activities on his behalf.

But the point here is- this token expires in 2 hours. But, you can **extend** this token upto 60 days. But after that, user needs to visit your app again to get the normal token again and you can then **refresh** that token to extend its validity again.

You can read *Expiration and Extending Tokens* section in this doc: [Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending)

(Just a suggestion) What you can do anytime user visits your app, extend it save on your server. So, the token wont expire until and unless user didn't visited your app for 60 days. And when you are close to 60 days send him some notification.